# How to set up a class two steps down?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, class

I'm getting a little confused how to set up a class that's two steps below the top-most one.

For instance, say I have a game called BoardGame. One of whose parameters in numberOfSquares.

The classes are setup like this:

`BoardGameSetupViewController > BoardGamePlayViewController > GameEngine`

BoardGameSetupViewController creates an instance of BoardGamePlayViewController after the number of squares has been chosen. BoardGamePlayViewController has the GameEngine class as a @property which has been @synthesised.

So how would I set up that GameEngine directly from BoardGameSetupViewController? To set up the numberOfSquares for instance?

So in BoardGameSetupViewController, I want to set the properties of the engine, but they don't seem to get passed on.

```
BoardGamePlayViewController *boardGamePlayViewController = [[BoardGamePlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BoardGameView" bundle:nil];

// this line doesn't work
boardGamePlayViewController.gameEngine.numberOfSquares = 12;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to create an instance of GameAEngine beofre you do the assignment boardGamePlayViewController.gameEngine.numberOfSquares = 12;   So,

```
GameEngine *gameEngine = [[GameEngine alloc] init];
boardGamePlayViewController.gameEngine = gameEngine;
boardGamePlayViewController.gameEngine.numberOfSquares = 12;
```

should work.